# mysql - drop unique constraint

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a foreign key which is also a unique key.
How can I remove the unique Key without removing the foreign key?

When I do :

```
ALTER TABLE affaire DROP KEY contact_client_id;
```

I am getting a : `ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'contact_client_id': needed in a foreign key constraint`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible because [foreign keys must be on indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Comment: If you still need the foreign key on `affaire`, is there another column that you can reference?